# How to take down plaster over drywall ceiling?

Tags: electrical, plaster

My ceiling is 3 layers and very heavy. Drywall, with plaster and ceiling tile over that. Looking for safest way to take down entire ceiling.

Comment: is there a requiremnt that your ceiling is fireproof?

Comment: What is above this ceiling?

Answer (score 1):

Need to know what is above it, cables, pipes(gas and water) first and where they are.

Remove as much as possible out of the room or have everything against one wall.  Cover anything left in the room plus the floor, it is going to get messy.

Hard hats, eye protection, gloves are needed.

Remove ceiling in small sections(cutting is good if you know what is above).    Clean room often of removed sections.  Removing small sections of ceiling by layers also better than trying to remove all layers at same time.

Know what is above first before cutting or pulling down with tools.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the layers from bottom to top are ceiling-tile, drywall, and plaster-on-lathing.  My wife and I have taken down dozens of ceilings with all of these combinations.  As noted, it is very, very messy;  eye, head, and foot protection is essential.  A filter mask is not unreasonable as there may be all sorts of dead stuff up there, not to mention dust.

Our technique is to start at one wall, cut the tape (if any), pry off an edge with a pry-bar, and continue.  We have found it easier to remove one layer at a time.  There are tools for removing drywall pieces (called poppers, of all things) but pry-bars work just as well.  Be careful as more may come down than you expect.  Popping off the lathing will take the plaster with it but take care because of its weight.  I would not advise the use of any power tools.